# Ruby, Sinatra views and class methods

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm learning how to use Sinatra. I figured out that when I pass object as locals, e.g.:

```
product = FetchProduct.new.call(id) #function finds exact Product instance
erb :"products/show", locals: { product: product }
```

I can use product object in my views with all instance methods I declared. But I can't use any class method, any attempt to do so gives me uninitialized constant error. What should I do if I want to use `Product.format_price(product.price)` method? Is there any way to pass class methods to Sinatra views?

Answer (score 1):

```
klass = const_get( product.class )
klass.format_price
```

But that doesn't really make sense because you already know you want `Product.format_price`. So why don't you use `Product.format_price`?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad idea to run that kind of logic in your views. Best practice is to, wherever possible, serve to the view whatever it needs.

NB the reason you can't run the class method in your view is because `Product` is not accessible in your view and, to be honest, it shouldn't be if you want to follow MVC principles.

If it's just the `format_price` method you need in the view (especially since you seem to be passing an instance of `Product` into `Product.format_price` which is rather strange and a big code smell), then either create a helper method called `format_price` that is accessible by the view or, probably better, create a helper method called `format_price` in your controller (or in a helper module included in your controller) and pass the return value as a local i.e.

```
get '/' do
  product = FetchProduct.new.call(id)
  erb :'products/show', locals: { 
    product: product, 
    price: format_price(product)
  }
end

private

def format_price(product)
  # awesome formatting logic
end
```